# Relation of the left/right inverse and column/row vector independence

Tags: linear-algebra

It is know that there is isomorphism between the set of all linear transformations $A:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and the set of all matrix $(a_{ij})_{n\times m}$. Furthermore, I know too that, if $A:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, then

- $A$ is injective if only if there is a left inverse $L:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ of $A$, i.e., $LA = I_{m}$
- $A$ is surjective if only if there is a right inverse $R:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ of $A$, i.e., $AR = I_{n}$

With this identification, I want to know what is the justification, in the context of linear transformations, that:

- A matrix $a = (a_{ij})_{n\times m}$ has left inverse iff his column vector are linear independents;
- A matrix $a = (a_{ij})_{n\times m}$ has right inverse iff his row vectors are linear independents.

For this question, it is supossed that there is no the notion of the transpose of matrix and the adjoint of linear transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution $x\in\Bbb R^m$ of $Ax=0$ gives a linear combination of the *column* vectors of $A$ resulting in the $0$ vector. Thus, $A$ is injective iff the column vectors of $A$ are linearly independent. Similarly, any solution $y\in\Bbb R^n$ of $yA = 0^\top$ gives a linear combination of the *row* vectors of $A$ resulting in the $0$ vector.

Comment: It is clear that: $A$ injective $\iff$ $[Ax = 0 \implies x= 0]$ $\iff$ the column vectors of $A$ are L.I.  But it is not clear that $A$ surjective $\iff$ $[yA = 0 \implies y= 0]$ $\iff$ the row vectors of $A$ are L.I.

Comment: In other words, I would like to prove that  $A$ surjective $\iff$ $[yA = 0 \implies y= 0]$

Comment: I am not sure what you're willing to use here (you've explicitly ruled out transpose). If the rows are linearly independent, there is no row of zeroes in the echelon form of $A$, and so $Ax=b$ has a solution for every $b\in\Bbb R^n$.